# Ordering a food menu by 2 columns: dish & dishprice MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to order by 2 columns: dish and dish price. They are both stored as strings so it casts the dishprice to Decimal. Its basically a takeaway food menu, so I want it to start with the lowest price item and end with the most expensive item. However, it's nice to have them in some sort of alphabetic order too. Here's what I'm getting for the sundries menu:

MS SQL:

```
SELECT dish, dishPrice, category FROM tbldishes ORDER BY CAST(dishPrice AS DECIMAL) ASC, dish ASC
```

Output:

```
Barbeque Sauce 0.85
Coke Zero 1.00
Coleslaw 0.85
Garlic Mayo 0.85
Pepsi Max 1.00
Chips 2.95
```

It want and would have expected this..

```
Barbeque Sauce 0.85
Coleslaw 0.85
Garlic Mayo 0.85
Coke Zero 1.00
Pepsi Max 1.00
Chips 2.95
```

Which keeps the sauces together and drinks together whilst still in price order. The menu's are obviously much bigger than this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you storing dishPrice as a string - you should always use the correct data type for the content - and if you do that the sort works btw

Comment: When I started the website which this is for, my programming skills were terrible and probably still are tbh. I will change it to storing prices as a decimal when I get chance, at the moment I can't afford for the site to go down for long. Should that affect anything in this case though? Once cast to decimal it should surely order them the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your query to

```
SELECT dish, CAST(dishprice), category FROM tbldishes
```

you will note that the second column is an integer in all cases (0,1,2)
try using

```
SELECT dish, dishPrice, category FROM tbldishes ORDER BY CAST(dishPrice AS DECIMAL(18,2)) , dish
```

Or better yet, use the correct data type in your table.

Comment: Ah that's exactly what I was missing. Thank you, that works as I wanted.